# Move XML element to different position with GDataXML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, gdata, gdataxml

I'm current using Google's GDataXML library to manipulate XML in my iOS app. The xml is used to populate a table view, so one thing I'd like to support (but current don't) is the ability to move a row in the table view to a different spot using `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`.

Is there a way to do this easily using GDataXML?

For example, let's say this is what my xml looks like:

```
<root>
    <section>    
        <item>
              <name>Item 1</name>
              <description>The first item</description>
        </item>
        <item>
              <name>Item 2</name>
              <description>The second item</description>
        </item>
        <item>
              <name>Item 3</name>
              <description>The third item</description>
        </item>
    </section>
</root>
```

What would I have to do to move `Item 3` to above where `Item 1` is? Would it be similar to inserting a new element to the front of an array?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Changed my example xml a bit. Could I just replace the whole `<section>` with a new one somehow?

UPDATE:

For anyone else wanting a method such as `insertChild:atIndex:`, check out the [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) library. The transition from GDataXML to KissXML is very easy as most of the method names are the same. The KissXML library builds off of Apple's XML classes and it has a `insertChild:atIndex:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form an mutable array with the items. Move around the items a bit and then you can save the items array as xml back.

You can write the xml this way. I have created an array of dictionaries with key name and description

```
GDataXMLElement *rootElement = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"root"];
GDataXMLElement *sectionElement = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"section"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in self.items) {

    GDataXMLElement *itemElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];

    GDataXMLElement *nameElement = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:dict[@"name"]];
    GDataXMLElement *descElement = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"description" stringValue:dict[@"description"]];

    [itemElement addChild:nameElement];
    [itemElement addChild:descElement];

    [sectionElement addChild:itemElement];

}

[rootElement addChild:sectionElement];



GDataXMLDocument *document = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]
                              initWithRootElement:rootElement];

NSData *xmlData = document.XMLData;
```

Now this xmlData can be written to fileLocation.

You can take a look to this [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestGDataXML.zip) for complete implementation.

Comment: Very in depth answer! So basically, to move elements around you have to re-create the xml document?

Comment: @EricAmorde I believe that's the way to handle reordering :)

Comment: Right, sorry I guess I was just wondering if the functionality was built in, Like a methods `insertNodeAtIndex:` or something. Thanks!